# How can we analyze the procedure Product: multiply two n-bits binary numbers x and y?

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to analyze the algorithm *Product*: multiply two n-bits binary numbers x and y.

```
function Product(x, y); 
 1. prod = 0;
 2. while y not eq 0
 3.     y = y -1;
 4.     prod = prod + x; 
    return prod;
```

Assume: n = |x| = |y|
Give the worst case time T(n) function for algorithm Product.
Express T(n) in terms of a big-Θ function in n.
Analysis:

T(n) = c1 + n + c2 + c3

I would appreciate it if someone could explain how to use big-Θ to express T(n).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Comment: No. This is very specific and follows the exact format for asking questions.

Comment: Do you know the definition of Θ ? If yes, do you understand it ?

Comment: When dealing with such low-level operations, we cannot be sure about the computational model. So you should specify the cost of an addition.

Comment: BTW, the downvotes are because you don't show any attempt.

Comment: I can't attach a pdf.

Comment: Something has gone wrong near $c2$ & $c3$. `can't attach a PDF` You can use $L^AT_EX$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer these two questions: How many iterations when n = 1 billion? How many iterations when n = -1?

With that you should have no problem answering your question.

Comment: Why the case n=-1 ?

Comment: while y ≠ 0. Never true if you start with y = -1.

Comment: Of course, but how is that useful to complexity analysis ?

Comment: It means the complexity analysis is totally off. There are instances where the execution doesn’t even end.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I did not consider that the OP said |y|=n. In fact, with this condition, T(n) is always infinite !

Answer (score 0):

line 1: c1
line 2: n
line 3: c2
line 4: c3
line 5: c4

T(n) = c1 + n + c2n + c3n + c4n
T(n) = theta(n)